# How to sum values based on different conditions in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have 3 columns which looks like the following.

```
Bucket      Amt     Fixed Amount
1           10       100
2           20       200
3           30       300
4+          40       400
```

I want to sum values from bucket 2 to 4+ and from bucket 3 to 4+ i.e., my final table should look like the below

```
Bucket      Amt     Fixed Amount
1           10       100
2           20       200
3           30       300
4+          40       400
2-4+        90       900
3-4+        70       700
```

I created 2 variables "2-4+" and "3-4+".
Assigned the Calculation to "Sum"
But how do I write an expression for the same which will sum the value for amt and fixed amount based on the bucket? Can I use conditional statements?
i.e.,for the first variable 2-4+ sum the value for amt and fixed amount for the buckets between 2 and 4+. Similarly for the second variable.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If each bucket is an output row in your query, and you know that the only calculations you will need to perform are "2-4+" and "3-4+", you might want to consider building the calculations into your query output.

Or -- you could try grouping on bucket. Display buckets 1, 2,3, 4+ in your detail band as you normally would. Create three variables to hold the results of buckets 2, 3, 4+ (calculation = nothing, reset type = group, reset group = bucket, and value expression = $F{bucket}). Then create two more variables to hold the results of "2-4+" and "3-4+" (calculation = nothing, value expression = $V{bucket_2}-$V{bucket_4} and $V{bucket_3}-$V{bucket_4}). Make sure that the variables that hold the bucket results are declared before the calculation variables. Display the output of your calculation variables in the group footer.

Answer (score 0):

For 2-4+, create a new variable and set its **Variable expression** to:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT} > 1 ? $F{Amt} : 0
```

For 3-4+, create a new variable and set its  **Variable expression** to:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT} > 2 ? $F{Amt} : 0
```